# Hide div created by script with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, embed

The following code creates an html chatbox with a link in the top panel that has multiple child divs. 
div id=cgroup; div id=CBG; div id=CGW; div id=HEAD. Where cgroup is the parent of CBG which is the parent of CGW which is the parent of the div I would like to hide.
How do I use css to "display = none" for the child div id=HEAD exclusively?

```
<script id="cid0020000101807397328" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 603px;height: 471px;">
{"handle":"1shotgg","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"000000","b":100,"c":"a0a0a0","d":"FFFFFF","e":"202020","g":"bbbbbb","h":"202020","j":"c0c0c0","k":"0084ef","l":"606060","m":"0084ef","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"000000","r":100,"pos":"br","cv":1,"cvfntsz":"14px","cvbg":"3366ff","cvw":600,"cvh":30,"surl":0,"allowpm":0,"cnrs":"0.35","ticker":1,"fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this loads the chatbox inside of an **`<iframe>`**, there is **not much you can do** to influence the style of individual elements on the page loaded into the `<iframe>`.

Any CSS applied to the parent page will **not apply to the page within the frame**. Similarly, if you try to alter the document within the frame with JavaScript, you are likely to get a security exception — the browser's **[Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)** will prevent your JavaScript code from accessing pages loaded from a **different domain**:

[image: Console output of trying to access <iframe> document]

To read more, refer to this question:
[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

---

**What's the solution then?**

You should try to see if the chatbox plugin provides the kind of customization you are looking for as a configuration option or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script creates an element with the structure `<div id="head">`, you can target it directly with the following syntax:

```
#head {
  display: none;
}
```

Despite the fact that you should never have two elements with the same ID on the same page, you can **ensure** that this hides **only** the target `<div>` by getting a little more specific and using the `>` **[direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**:

```
#cgroup > #CBG > #CGW > #head {
  display: none;
}
```

The above will **only** target a `<div>` with an `ID` of `<head>`, where the parent has an ID of `CGW`, and that has a parent ID of `CBG`, and that has a parent ID of `cgroup`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I thought it would be that easy way before posting this question because the script does in fact create the child div HEAD that I want to hide.  Unfortunately that wasn't the resolution.  Thinking it might be case sensitive I also tried the marker #HEAD to no avail .

Comment: Are you running the script in an `<iframe>`? If so, it's impossible to style the code from another website due to [**Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). You may find that the chatbox offers some customisation options in that case.